# jQuery mouseover hover mouseout remove set variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following to bring in a picture and some text from another page through jquery on a hover over of an area map. I've got it working find when you hover, but when you hover over a new element it loads the last element and then quickly flicks to the new element. How can I clear what it has saved on the mouse out? I've added the mouseout function but I have no idea what to put in it! Any help will be much appreciated.

```
if (sPage == "fireplan.aspx") {
    jQuery('area').mousemove(function (e) {

        var url = jQuery(this).attr('tooltiphref');

        jQuery('#tooltipwindow').load('tooltip.aspx?soid=' + url);
        jQuery("#tooltipwindow").css("position", "fixed").css("top", (e.pageY - jQuery(window).scrollTop()) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX) + "px").css("display", "none").fadeIn("fast")
    });

    jQuery('area').mouseout(function () {



    });


}
```

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the "flickering" is because the old content is still inside the tooltip window when it moves since your call to `.load()` will take some time in comparison to moving the tooltip via `.css()` on the next line.

To avoid this, simply put something like the following inside your `mouseout` handler:

`jQuery('#tooltipwindow').empty()`

That will remove what was previously loaded into the tooltip, so its content will simply appear blank. A more ideal approach would be to insert some kind of activity indicator to let the user know that content is loading, like:

`jQuery('#tooltipwindow').html('<div class="activityIndicator"></div>')`

In this case, you'd just set the class `.activityIndicator` to have some background image, like an animated GIF of a spinning wheel.

Comment: This seems the logical answer, however from breakpointing the code the mouseout seems to run all the time and still flickers between the new picture :(

Comment: There is a chance I could've missed a } or similar as re-writing this again seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Show the tooltip from the success-callback of load, that way you know your new content has been loaded prior to showing the the tooltip.

```
jQuery('#tooltipwindow').load('tooltip.aspx?soid=' + url, function() {
    jQuery("#tooltipwindow").css("position", "fixed").css("top", (e.pageY - jQuery(window).scrollTop()) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX) + "px").css("display", "none").fadeIn("fast")    
});
```

Also, if you want to create a hover effect, you probably want to listen for the mouseover-event, instead of the mousemove-event that you are using know with the `mousemove()` method.

Comment: While this would solve the immediate "flickering" problem, it will produce a horrible UI because it will seem unresponsive to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to affect the first div?  If so, why don't you make your jQuery selector more specific so that it only applies to the first element:

```
$('area.first_area').mousemove(function(){ });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('area').mousemove(function (e) {

    var url = jQuery(this).attr('tooltiphref');
    jQuery('#tooltipwindow').empty(); // empty before loading new content
    jQuery('#tooltipwindow').load('tooltip.aspx?soid=' + url);

    jQuery("#tooltipwindow").css("position", "fixed").css("top", (e.pageY - jQuery(window).scrollTop()) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX) + "px").css("display", "none").fadeIn("fast")
});


jQuery('area').mouseout(function () {
    jQuery('#tooltipwindow').empty();  // empty when mouseout get triggered
});
```